# HTML form exhibiting strange behaviour ONLY in IE7

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I've been working on a new page for a company website, and have succeeded in styling the form exactly as specified. The form displays correctly in all browsers other than IE7, but despite multiple searches of StackOverflow and Google with varied keywords, I've not been able to find any similar problems or solutions.

I attempted to replicate the behaviour in a jsfiddle, but had no luck. Instead, I shall attach two screenshots of the before and after behaviour, plus snippets of relevant code.

[image]

This first image shows how the form should look, and this is how it is displayed when the browser first loads the page. However, the form behaviour is somewhat erratic, and the following change takes effect either when the user begins to type in the input box or clicks submit, on a seemingly random basis.

[image]

This is the HTML code I'm using, nothing fancy:

```
<form id="enquiry" action="/guides/thanks" method="post">
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="firstname">First name*:</label>
        <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" size="40" value="{{firstname | escape }}" {{ is_missing("firstname") }} />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="lastname">Last name*:</label>
        <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" size="40" value="{{lastname | escape }}" {{ is_missing("lastname") }} />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email*:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="40" value="{{email | escape }}" {{ is_missing("email") }} />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email2">Confirm email*:</label>
        <input id="email2" type="text" name="email2" size="40" value="{{email2 | escape }}" {{ is_missing("email2") }}/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="organization">organization*:</label>
        <input id="organization" type="text" name="organization" size="40" value="{{organization | escape }}" {{ is_missing("organization") }}/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="position">Job title:</label>
        <input id="position" type="text" name="position" size="40" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="country">Country*:</label>
      <select id="country" name="country" value="{{country | escape }}" {{ is_missing("country") }}>
            <option value="">Choose&hellip;</option>
            <option disabled="disabled" value="">----</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option disabled="disabled" value="">----</option>

            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            ...
            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>

        </select>

    </li>
    <br>
    <div>
    <li class="submit-row">
    <input class="link-button download-button" type="submit" value="Submit your details" />
    <br><br><input class="link-button" type="submit" value="Submit your details" />
    </li>
</form>
```

And as much relevant CSS as possible (#primary-content is a container div):

```
li label {
    margin-left: -115px;
}
form#enquiry ul li input.link-button {
    margin-left: 110px;
}
.missinginput {
    border : red;
}
form#enquiry p.error-tip {
    left: 350px;
}

#primary-content form  {
  font-size:90%;
}

#primary-content form fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#primary-content form fieldset legend {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#primary-content form label {
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#primary-content form fieldset dl, dl#form-dl {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
#primary-content form fieldset dl dt, dl#form-dl dt {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#primary-content form fieldset dl dd, dl#form-dl dd {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 210px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The code you've given us isn't sufficient. It doesn't come close to reproducing either the correct or incorrect layouts you've described. You appear to be using a templating engine of some sort: it's all over your code, but you haven't mentioned it in the question; perhaps you could tell us about it, because there's a strong chance it'll be relevant, especially if it's client-side javascript code, and if it updates the DOM in real-time. Have you confirmed that your template library is IE7 compatible? And what do the `is_missing()` calls do?

Comment: The templating engine is Jinja/Flask, and other than adding borders to fields when required, it doesn't affect the DOM in a way that could cause this behaviour. is_missing() checks that all required fields are filled in, and if not, adds a red border and .error class to them. After some more fiddling with my code, I discovered that the problem lay in the width of <ul> objects being set elsewhere in the base css file. Thanks for your comment, though.

Comment: As my rep is < 10, I won't be able to resolve this for another 7 hours.

Comment: does that mean you've found the problem? well done.

Comment: I think it has to do something with the old float problem described here : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html
And ofcourse to avoid quirks mode you should proper close the brake tags `<br/>` and the `div` and the `ul` at the begging should have closing tag as well. I've prepared a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/gRGXc/

Comment: <div> and <ul> are both closed in my code, just didn't copy far enough down to include them in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. I discovered that the width of

```
form#enquiry ul li label
```

objects were set to 220px elsewhere in my CSS, and this, combined with

```
li label {
    margin-left: -115px;
}
```

was causing problems. Setting the width to 125px and the margin-left to 0px appears to have resolved the problem.